# " Error App Domain is not a valid domain." But It IS a valid domain

Tags: api, authentication, facebook-authentication

Trying to register app gave me:

Error App Domain: http://www.universalfather.info is not a valid domain.

But it IS a valid domain. Is this because it is a ".info" website?

Comment: Perhaps it's asking for a *domain*, not a *URL*, which means leave out the `http://` part. I don't know; I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 3):

Add "universalfather.info" as domain and http://www.universalfather.info as siteURL.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Alex's answer is correct, but you may also have a problem because your base domain (without the www) isn't resolving an A record:

```
host universalfather.info
universalfather.info mail is handled by 10 mx1.webhero.com.
universalfather.info mail is handled by 20 mx2.webhero.com.
```

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem.  the error log is sketchy.  this is the solution:

```
1st goto WEBSITE (below SELECT HOW YOUR APP CONNECTS...) and click
2nd in the text area, fill in your website         http://www.yourdomain.info
3rd go back to APP DOMAIN (BASIC INFO) and type    yourdomain.info
```

This absolutely works but I didn't quite understand the instructions, so I'm going to restate them for other neophytes like myself.

1. From the Facebook development page "Apps-YourAppName", click on Basic in the LEFT Nav.
2. There are 3 sections on this page:  Basic Info, Cloud Services, and "Select how your app integrates with Facebook"
3. In the Select how your app integrates with Facebook section, select "Website"
4. Enter your fully qualified domain name in the Site URL dialog box.  Example:  http://www.mydomain.com OR http://mydomain.com    (my site does not include the www so I didn't add it).
5. At the bottom of the page click the "Save Changes" button.  You may receive a notice that it may take several minutes to blah blah blah....but you can continue with the next steps immediately.
6. Now, in the Basic Information section at the top of this screen, you can now add your App Domain.  This should be formatted as mydomain.com.  Do not add "http://" and do not add "/" at the end of the domain name.

NOTE:  My site does not use the www, so I cannot confirm that it's required in Step #6.  Try it both ways if you're unsure.

1. At the bottom of the page click the "Save Changes" button.  You may receive a notice that it may take several minutes to blah blah blah....but you can continue with the next steps immediately.
2. At this point the error was NOT displayed as it was before.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a valid domain to Facebook

http://graph.facebook.com/10150472668498918

```
{
   "url": "http://www.universalfather.info/",
   "type": "website",
   "title": "KINGDOM OF HEAVEN REVELATION",
   "image": [
      {
         "url": "http://www.universalfather.info/png/Universal_Father_img.png"
      }
   ],
   "updated_time": "2012-01-26T02:07:50+0000",
   "id": "10150472668498918"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This absolutely works but I didn't quite understand the instructions, so I'm going to restate them for other neophytes like myself.

1. From the Facebook development page "Apps-YourAppName", click on Basic in the LEFT Nav.
2. There are 3 sections on this page: Basic Info, Cloud Services, and "Select how your app integrates with Facebook"
3. In the Select how your app integrates with Facebook section, select "Website"
4. Enter your fully qualified domain name in the Site URL dialog box. Example: http://www.mydomain.com OR http://mydomain.com (my site does not include the www so I didn't add it).
5. At the bottom of the page click the "Save Changes" button. You may receive a notice that it may take several minutes to blah blah blah....but you can continue with the next steps immediately.
6. Now, in the Basic Information section at the top of this screen, you can now add your App Domain. This should be formatted as mydomain.com. Do not add "http://" and do not add "/" at the end of the domain name.
7. NOTE: My site does not use the www, so I cannot confirm that it's required in Step #6. Try it both ways if you're unsure.
8. At the bottom of the page click the "Save Changes" button. You may receive a notice that it may take several minutes to blah blah blah....but you can continue with the next steps immediately.
9. At this point the error was NOT displayed as it was before.

Hope this helps!